# How to add user from office 365 to a list

Tags: sharepoint, office365, csom

If i want to add a user to listitem i must used the code :

var listItem = list.GetItemById(idoftheuser);

But the trouble is that my user is not present on the list and on the site. But he is present in the user of office 365.

How can i add a user in that case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things involved here :

1) A Office 365 user , need not necessarily have access to SharePoint Online as well, It depends on the License . In the Office365 Admin section, check the license associated with the user, and see if it covers SharePoint Online.

2) In the SharePoint Admin Section , check the active user profiles and check if the mentioned user is available.

3) Add a user to a list, requires the user being a "Site User" as well. Lookup for method EnsureUser [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx).

4) Finally your code seems incorrect, for Adding a user. The code you have providedd is to **Get** a list item , so the parameter must be the id of the list item you want.

```
var listItem = list.GetItemById(idofthelistItem);
```

Comment: Sorry,
i made a bad copy paste, it was not the right code.

Comment: Congratulations, even a code unrelated to the question you gave me the right answer.

Thank you.